# Network extension web content filter not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-content, networkextension

I have added the Network extension to my app successfully for web content filtering. I have the entitlement file checked and capabilities added as well. I have also pushed web-content filtering payload from my server which has my app's bundle identifier and type as plug-in. However, I have installed the app on a supervised device. But none of my log statements get printed from the extension. I haven't configured any rules so far. Just want the extension to run. Am I missing something ? Any assistance on the same would do a world of good ! Thanks in advance.
P.S. I am using XCode 9.2(objective-c) and device functioning on iOS 11.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `consele.app` to display both iOS and Mac logs which is already installed on your Mac. Search for `console` from your **Spotlight** and after opening the app select your iOS device under **Devices** from left panel. You can display all system logs including your extension's logs.

A small note for **Swift** developers don't forget to use `NSLog` to display logs from console app.